# Yii: Print code as string

Tags: php, yii

I want print some block of code as an string. The block contains string as well as variable.

```
echo "array(
            'name' => 'postby_id',
            'value' => '$data->postby->username',
            'filter' => CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'username')
     ),";
```

Comment: What is your desired output? At the moment it is not clear what you're asking. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Are you writing a tutorial and the code needs to be displayed as code, or do you want the result of the array displayed on screen, like with `print_r()`?

Comment: @TomFenech, I am planning to change my template code. So, I want to display the code as it is. In my question there is one variable, $data->postby->username. The variable sholud be printed as it is not its value. ' ' is not working in this case & " " requires value.

Comment: @RST, I have to display code as it is if it contains some variable. Here variable is $data->postby->username.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you could do is something like

```
<?php
 // some code
?>
array(
         'name' => 'postby_id',
         'value' => '$data->postby->username',
         'filter' => CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'username')
     ),
<?php
// rest of your code
```

just the way you can output HTML in a .php file. But I am not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: No. It's not a solution what I am expecting for. All the code plus text inside echo " " should be printed. I can accept if all lines are printed in only one. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just flip single and double quotes and you should be good to go.

PHP parses the contents of a double-quoted string, and doesn't parse the contents of a single-quoted string.

> Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape
>   sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur
>   in single quoted strings.

[PHP Manual -> Language -> Reference -> Types -> Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

For example, if you want to not evaluate the variables (and other stuff), do this:

```
$var = 'not printed';
echo 'The variable $var is not to be evaluated';
```

Would print:

> The variable $var is not to be evaluated

```
$var = 'not printed';
echo "The variable is not $var";
```

Would print:

> The variable is not not printed